# How to deploy PhoneGap app in multiple Platforms

Tags: xcode, cordova

Created one app using phonegap in Xcode, want to deploy that into multiple platforms like android phone and etc.

Can any one please give the answer, how can i achive this.

Answer (score 1):

Take the contents of the "www" folder of your application and copy them into the "phonegap/lib/DESIREDPLATFORM/sample/www" where DESIREDPLATFORM stands for the target platform (I.E.: blackberry, android, etc). All files should be copied, except for the "phonegap.js" file, which is specific to each platform.

after that, go to the command prompt, navigate to the phonegap "sample" folder, and compile the application with "ant DESIREDPLATFORM compile" (you already know what DESIREDPLATFORM stands for). It will create the  appropriate package for the platform.

Comment: I Used CoreDova template to create this app...in that situation also is this the procedure to create multiple platforms builds...because i am unable to find the folders what you mentioned

Comment: found this in some random SO question: "When you create a project with Cordova template it has a setup for a sample page. When you run the project first time it creates a /www folder, that should work as it is." Also, phonegap folders should be installed as well.

Comment: yes, i have my www folder and i am able to run my app on my iphone successfully but i want to install the same app in my samsung android phone, i don't have any idea how to do this.

Comment: in my answer, the "phonegap" folder is the one where you installed phonegap. If you don't have this, just install it.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to create a repository(either public or private depending on your need) of your assets folder and using the phonegap build app, you can find it here: https://build.phonegap.com. I have tested that and it works great.